# How to create an array of objects based on values of another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 8 players `ab`,`cd`,`ef`,`gh`,`ij`,`kl`,`mn`,`op` their match data is stored in an array of objects

```
  matchData=[
              {player1:'ab',player2:'cd',winner:'ab',looser:'cd'},
              {player1:'ef',player2:'gh',winner:'gh',looser:'ef'},
              {player1:'ij',player2:'kl',winner:'ij',looser:'kl'},
              {player1:'mn',player2:'op',winner:'mn',looser:'op'},
              {player1:'ab',player2:'cd',winner:'ab',looser:'cd'},
              {player1:'ij',player2:'kl',winner:'kl',looser:'ij'},
              {player1:'ij',player2:'kl',winner:'ij',looser:'kl'}]
```

I want to get the top player from the above match data.The Top player is the one who is having the highest win rate

```
winrate=(number of matches won/total number of matches played)*100
```

And also want to get the array of objects which look like,

```
PlayerData=[{ab:87},{cd:78},{ef:57},{gh:75},{ij:47},{kl:14},{mn:65},{op:44}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: One way to do it would be to loop through your array, count the number of wins for each player individually and add it to some summed value for each player. Then whoever has the most amounts of wins has the highest winrate and make some condition around that. You can then create a new empty array and `push` your desired values into your array with the structure you desire.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can loop though data and create new array for each winner/looser adding in 1 if wins else 0 if looses. Then calculate percentage of wins from new array object.

```js
matchData = [
              {player1:'ab',player2:'cd',winner:'ab',looser:'cd'},
              {player1:'ef',player2:'gh',winner:'gh',looser:'ef'},
              {player1:'ij',player2:'kl',winner:'ij',looser:'kl'},
              {player1:'mn',player2:'op',winner:'mn',looser:'op'},
              {player1:'ab',player2:'cd',winner:'ab',looser:'cd'},
              {player1:'ij',player2:'kl',winner:'kl',looser:'ij'},
              {player1:'ij',player2:'kl',winner:'ij',looser:'kl'}
]

let tempRes = {}
for (let d of matchData) {
  let { winner, looser } = d
  
  tempRes[winner] = (tempRes[winner] || []).concat(1)
  tempRes[looser] = (tempRes[looser] || []).concat(0)
  
}

let res = [], topPlayers = [], topValue = 0
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(tempRes)) {
  let winPercent = (value.reduce((a,b) => a + b) / value.length) * 100
  res.push({ [key]: winPercent })

  winPercent == topValue && (topPlayers.push(key))
  winPercent > topValue && (topValue = winPercent, topPlayers = [key])
}

console.log('Top Player ', topPlayers)
console.log('Result ',res)
```

Comment: If two there are two top players have same winrate,How to get the top players as an array?

Comment: @Arjunsr updated the answer.

Comment: It's always better to tweak the code yourself to reach to desired solution. This helps in understanding code/logic better. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -1):

You may *reduce* the input data to represent lost/win stats for each player, and then you may apply the formula to each player stats to get the desired output:

```js
const matchData = [{
    player1: 'ab',
    player2: 'cd',
    winner: 'ab',
    looser: 'cd'
  },
  {
    player1: 'ef',
    player2: 'gh',
    winner: 'gh',
    looser: 'ef'
  },
  {
    player1: 'ij',
    player2: 'kl',
    winner: 'ij',
    looser: 'kl'
  },
  {
    player1: 'mn',
    player2: 'op',
    winner: 'mn',
    looser: 'op'
  },
  {
    player1: 'ab',
    player2: 'cd',
    winner: 'ab',
    looser: 'cd'
  },
  {
    player1: 'ij',
    player2: 'kl',
    winner: 'kl',
    looser: 'ij'
  },
  {
    player1: 'ij',
    player2: 'kl',
    winner: 'ij',
    looser: 'kl'
  }
]

const winRate = ({ lost, won }) => (won / (won + lost)) * 100

const calcStats = results => results.reduce ((out, { winner, looser }) => {
    (out[looser] || (out[looser] = { lost: 0, won: 0 })).lost++ 
    (out[winner] || (out[winner] = { lost: 0, won: 0 })).won++ 
    
    return out
  },
  {}
)


const calcWinRate = stats => 
      Object.entries (stats)
            .map (([ player, stats ]) => ({
                [player]: winRate (stats) 
            }))
            
const output = calcWinRate (calcStats (matchData))

console.log (output)
```

Comment: Why I got a downvote?

Comment: I suspect it's because the OP has provided no attempted solution, but sometimes it's a chance for others to discover different approaches to solve the same issue.

Comment: Same downvotes to my solution